# Accessing/wrapping a struct inside a class in Cython

Tags: c++, class, struct, cython

I am trying to wrap the btCollisionWorld C++ class of the Bullet Physics library with Cython. I have had good success generally with the physics simulation parts of the library but I have run into trouble trying to wrap the collision detection parts.

If you look at https://github.com/kripken/bullet/blob/master/src/BulletCollision/CollisionDispatch/btCollisionWorld.h you will find the .h file that contains the btCollisionWorld class that I am trying to wrap. This is actually a somewhat newer version than what I am working with but I believe it is the same in the important respects.

(Also if you look at https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/Raycast/RaytestDemo.cpp you will see an example C++ program that makes use of the library. That may be helpful additional context to show the kind of thing I want to be able to do in Cython, and what I can do for the normal physics part of Bullet Physics.)

Generally I can access some parts of the btCollisionWorld class through Cython. For example, if I put the following in my .pxd file:

```
cdef cppclass btCollisionWorld:
    btBroadphaseInterface* getBroadphase()
```

then in in my Cython code I can successfully compile and execute lines like this:

```
if cw.getBroadphase():
    print "the test passed, we can access a member function in btCollisionWorld"
```

However, when I try to extend my .pxd to provide access to (for example) "struct LocalShapeInfo" by making the .pxd look like this:

```
cdef cppclass btCollisionWorld:
    btBroadphaseInterface* getBroadphase()
    struct LocalShapeInfo:
        int m_shapePart
```

then attempts to access it from Cython using code like this:

```
print "can a member of a struct be accessed?", cw.LocalShapeInfo.m_shapePart
```

give errors like this:

```
print "can a member of a struct be accessed?", cw.LocalShapeInfo.m_shapePart
                                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun6.pyx:1428:53: Object of type 'btCollisionWorld' has no attribute 'LocalShapeInfo'
```

You can see from the above referenced .h file that LocalShapeInfo is just a struct inside the btCollisionWorld class. But I can't get to it from Cython!

I have tried MANY variants of the syntax for defining the structs in the .pxd file and nothing seems to work. I CANNOT ACCESS STRUCTS INSIDE CLASSES FROM CYTHON!! I don't see any examples of using Cython to access structs *declared inside classes*. Is this supported? If so, how? I can access member functions and member variables, but not structs, no matter how I declare them in the .pxd and how I access them from Cython. I am compiling with c++ options.

I may well be doing something dumb, but I tried many things. The problem above is actually just a first obstacle to getting my real problems solved but since it seemed pretty fundamental and contained I thought I would tackle it here first.

By the way, in the past I asked about instantiating a struct *derived* from a class. In this question the struct is *declared inside the class*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just failing to distinguish between the type name and the member name. Something like this works for me (at least gets through the cython stage):

```
cdef extern from *:
    cdef cppclass btCollisionWorld:
        struct LocalShapeInfo:
            int m_shapePart
        LocalShapeInfo m_shape
        
cdef f(btCollisionWorld& r):
    return r.m_shape.m_shapePart
```